# handling loading a table with buttons (newest, newer, older)

Tags: jquery

I am making a site that displays a tabled list with records. The server side sets the max limit of records on the page. The user can select the newest page with max limit records or the next limit oder (and back newer) records.
I am going to work with ajax requests and was wondering if I got the design right for this. My code is:

```
    function getTable(page, limit) {
```

`// this function ajax loads and displays a table from the server
// page and limit are parameters in the URI: activities/ajax/page#limit
// limit is set by server in the div #table on page load
}
$(document).ready(function(){
var page = 1; // default get the first page
var lim = $("#table").data("lim"); // get the limit 

$("#newer").prop("disabled", true); // start out with Newer disabled

$("#newest").click(function(){
    $("#newer").prop("disabled", true);
    page = 1;
    getTable(page, lim);
});

$("#newer").click(function(){
    page = page - lim;
    if (page < lim) {page = 1; $("#newer").prop("disabled", true);}
    getTable(page, lim);
});

$("#older").click(function(){
    $("#newer").prop("disabled", false);
    page = page + lim;
    getTable(page, lim);
});
});`

Does this make sense? Testing shows it is working by just page throught the buttons.

Comment: The code looks ok for me. But if this is working what you want us to do?

Comment: Jquery datatables with server side pagination should be a good solution in this case

Comment: @franco, vanojx1. I just wanted to make sure that my solution makes sense, since i am a beginner at javascript. So thanks for the feedback